# Certain page won't scroll - wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, loops, scroll, custom-post-type

I feel like I have come across some kind of bug. In Wordpress I am making my own theme. (currently local) I made a template for my home page (not my post page). Just to keep things simple, here is an example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Work Template
 *
 * Selectable from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Content</p>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I am using this exact same layout form my home page and my about page. Different Template Name of course. The content in the home page is a loop pulling a custom post type. For some reason the home page can't scroll at all. I tried removing the loop and just leaving the above code and it doesn't scroll. I understand that there is not enough content here to actually scroll the page. But It doen't even [rubber band](http://www.techanger.com/ios-like-edge-bounce-effect-google-chrome/). It's like scrolling has been disabled for the home page? And nothing is position fixed. I haven't ever heard of this before. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Go to your wp-config.php file and change define('WP_DEBUG', false); to define('WP_DEBUG', true); and reload the page to see if you get any errors.

Comment: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'create_post_type_work' not found or invalid function name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/calvinbramlett/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 429

Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method easyFancyBox::enqueue_styles() should not be called statically in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/calvinbramlett/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 429

Comment: Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method easyFancyBox::register_scripts() should not be called statically in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/calvinbramlett/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 429

Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method easyFancyBox::main_script() should not be called statically in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/calvinbramlett/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 429

Comment: Do you have any plugins enabled? If so, disable them all, and try again.

Comment: @NickM Thanks! I think it was a lightbox plugin that was giving the issue.

Comment: No worries! When the page cuts off like that it made me think that php threw an error, and then stopped outputting. Thus checking the debug logs. Obviously the /plugin.php error made me think plugins. Just FYI for next time :)

Good luck in the land of WP theme dev!